# Creating file of domain names and ips to bytes

Tags: python

I am trying load a pickle file in such a byte format:

```
(lp1
ccollections
Counter
p2
((dp3
S'\x80'
I7
sS'\x89'
I1
sS'\x91'
I1
sS'\x94'
```

And I have list of domains and ip address that I will create ngram for. But first I need to create a pickle file. Such an example, I want to turn the following `rocketleague.psyonix.com.,206.188.198.49` to the format above so it can perform look up.

How do I do that? and what is the best way to do it?

Thank you